# Square Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers

Are there Fibonacci numbers other than $F_0 = 0 = 0^2, F_1 = F_2 = 1 = 1^2,$ and $F_{12} = 144 = 12^2$ which are square numbers? If not, what is the proof?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is [a paper of Bugeaud, Mignotte, and Siksek](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403046v1.pdf) proving that

> the only perfect powers in the Fibonacci sequence are 0, 1, 8, 144

Therefore the only squares are 0, 1, and 144.

Answer (score 13):

0, 1 and 144 are the only perfect squares. See the proof [here](https://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/SquareFibonacci.html).

Comment: Nice!  Unlike the proof from the other answer, this one is elementary. Indeed, the proof you linked to is cited in Bugeaud, Mignotte and Siksek's paper.

Comment: I think point (9) is false as written. $L_{-n} = (-1)^n L_n$ is true, but what's written is $L_{-n} = (-1)^{n-1}L_n$ **notice the exponent**. I'm still not sure if point (9) is used as written or if it is just incorrectly written but the true statement was used.

Comment: The exponent in point (9) is just a transcription error. The original article in the Fibonacci Quarterly has the correct exponent.