# Is it a coincidence that the 12th Fibonacci number is 12 squared?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers

The first $12$ Fibonacci numbers are:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n  & 0& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8 & 9&  10& 11& 12\\
\hline
f_{n} & 0& 1& 1& 2& 3& 5& 8& 13& 21& 34& 55& 89& 144\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

When you get to $f_{12}$ you find it is equal to $144$.

What strikes me here is the following:

\begin{align*}
f_{12} &= 144\\
12^2 &=144.
\end{align*}

Not only is $f_{12}$ equal to $144$, but so is $12^2$. Here, $n^2= f_n$.

This is the only example as  $n^2 > f_n$ is true for all $1<n<12$ (works for $0$ and $1$) and $n^2< f_n$ is true for all $n > 12$.

**So is this just a coincidence?**

Comment: $f_0=0^2$ and $f_1=1^2$ as well. But yes, they are coincidences.

Comment: @dezdichado edited

Comment: Except from $0,1,144$ the only perfect power in whole sequence is $8$.

Comment: A small comment: note that because of its growth rate, for *any* polynomial $p$ there will be only finitely many (perhaps no) $n$ such that $p(n)=f(n)$.

Comment: The fifth Fibonacci number is 5.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil check out the LaTeX `align*` environment for aligning multiple equations, it is much simpler than setting the spacing manually.

Comment: @DMcMor yeah thanks, couldn't figure out how to do that

Comment: The numbers coincide. So indeed a coincidence :-).

Comment: @kingW3 do you have a proof of this ?

Comment: A number $x$ is a Fibonacci-number (contained in the sequence of Fibonacci-numbers), if and only if $5x^2-4$ or $5x^2+4$ (or both) is a perfect square. Maybe this could lead to an explanation ...

Comment: @Peter Here's a [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012999/square-fibonacci-numbers) to the question,found it when I was searching for similar questions.

Comment: @kingW3 Nice, only two perfect powers (if we ignore the trivial ones $0$ and $1$). Would not have expected that and that it was proven!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very nice manifestation of the [Strong Law of Small Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers) formulated by [Richard K. Guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_K._Guy): 
*"There aren't enough small numbers to meet the many demands made of them."*

A more striking manifestation of the same "law" of small numbers is this:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n  & 0& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8 & 9&  10& 11& 12\\
\hline
\mbox{Fibonacci }
f_{n} & 0& 1& 1& 2& 3& 5& 8& 13& 21& 34& 55& 89& 144\\
\hline
\hline
\mbox{# squares in }[e^{n-1},e^n)
      & 0& 1& 1& 2& 3& 5& 8& 13& 21& 36& 58& 96& 159\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The last line is [OEIS A306486](https://oeis.org/A306486): the number of squares in the interval $[e^{n-1},e^n)$, which happens to be the same as the Fibonacci number $f_n$ for $0\le n\le 8$. Note that both $f_n$ and A306486($n$) grow about as fast as certain geometric progressions; the common ratio is $\phi\approx1.618\ldots$ for the former and $\sqrt{e}\approx1.6487\ldots$ for the latter.