# Factor $x^5-x+15$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quintics

It's possible to factor $x^5-x+15$. WolframAlpha gives the answer of: $$(x^2+x+3)(x^3-x^2-2x+5)$$

According to the wikipedia article on quintic functions, the general form $x^5-x+a$ is factorable only when $a=±15$, $±22440$, or $±2759640$.

**Question:** How would one factor such an expression? For me, it seems close to impossible by hand.

**Bonus question:** Why do those specific values of $a$ make the expression factorable? If there's no simple answer, is there a paper/further reading about it?

Comment: It also factors when $a=0$, $a=\pm 30$, $a=\pm 240$, $a=\pm 1020$, and so on - the cases with an integer root. There must be something more to the statement excluding those cases.

Comment: You're right. "[The form] has solutions in radicals if and only if it has an integer solution or r is one of ±15, ±22440, or ±2759640, in which cases the polynomial is reducible."

Comment: I would say that factorization into radicals is a special case of factorization, and the fact that there is no factorization of some polynomial _into radicals_ does not imply there is no factorization at all. For any real number $a,$ the equation $x^5-x+a=0$ has at least one real root; if $\beta$ is the least root, then $x^5-x+a=(x-\beta)(x^4+\beta x^3+\beta^2x^2+\beta^3x+(\beta^4-1)).$ That's a factorization. The catch is that $\beta$ cannot be written in radicals except in the special cases named in the question or when $a=n^5-n$ for some integer $n.$

Comment: The finiteness of the list and the method of factoring come down to the fact that the largest square Fibonacci number is $144$

Comment: I would also consider doing modular factorization first? Factorization w.r.t. a prime modulus is reasonably fast, and we can then Chinese Remainder Theorem -combine several primes. Also Hensel lifting a factorization to a prime power modulus should quickly cull the search space. Here it is easy to see that modulo two the factorization is $(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1$, so we already know that *a quadratic times a cubic* is the only alternative. Need to try this some other day to see how quickly it is resolved.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen once you try it, let me know. I don't know modular arithmetic too much, but I'm sure it would be interesting!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can factor $$f(x) := x^5 - x \pm 15$$ manually (over $\Bbb Z$) without too much fuss.

First, if $f$ has a linear factor, it has a rational root and (because $f$ is monic) any rational root must be an integer. But $f(0) \equiv f(1) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, so $f$ has no root modulo $2$ and hence no integer root and hence no linear factor. (Alternatively, we can show this with the Rational Root Theorem; see the bottom of this answer.)

Thus, if $f$ factors, it must factor as a product of a cubic and a quadratic, that is, (where we denote $\Lambda = \pm 15$)
$$x^5 - x + \Lambda = (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + C) (x^2 + D x + E)$$
for some integers $A, B, C, D, E$. Distributing the right-hand side and comparing coefficients gives various (at most) quadratic conditions on those integers:
\begin{align}
A + D &= 0 \\
A D + B + E &= 0 \\
A E + B D + C &= 0 \\
B E + C D &= - 1 \\
C E &= \Lambda \\
\end{align}
We can quickly reduce this system: The first equation gives $D = -A$, so the second equation gives $E = A^2 - B$, and then the third equation becomes $C = -A^3 + 2 A B$. Substituting leaves the system
\begin{align*}
A^4 - A^2 B - B^2 &= -1 \\
A (A^2 - 2 B) (A^2 - B) &= \Lambda .
\end{align*}
Since $A, A^2 - 2 B, A^2 - B$ are all integers and the prime factorization of $|\Lambda| = 15$ is $3 \cdot 5$, there are only a small number of combinations to check (in fact, since $15$ is a product of two primes, one of the three factors must be $\pm 1$), and we can quickly recover the factorization mentioned in the question.

**Remark** For readers unfamiliar with reducing polynomial equations modulo primes, we can conclude that $f$ has no linear factor with just a little more work, using the Rational Root Theorem, which in this case implies that the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 15$; substituting shows that none of these are roots. One can even avoid most of this work: The derivative of the polynomial is $f'(x) = 5 x^4 - 1$, so $f$ is increasing where $|x| \geq 1$, but $f(-3) = -69, f(-1) = 13, f(1) = 15$, from which we can conclude none of the eight candidates are roots.

Answer (score 5):

The statement on Wikipedia cites a [1998 paper](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/36-3/elia.pdf) dealing with the solutions of $x^k-x=n$ for nonnegative integer $n$ and $k=3,4,5$. In turn this paper cites another paper by Rabinowitz ("The Factorization of $x^5\pm x+n$", *Math. Magazine* **61.3** (1988), 191–193) showing that if $x^5-x-r$ has no linear factor yet is reducible over the integers, then one of the two equations below is true:
$$r=\pm F_{2j-1}F_{2j}\sqrt{F_{2j+2}}\tag1$$
$$r=\pm F_{2j}F_{2j+1}\sqrt{F_{2j-2}}\tag2$$
The three specific $r$ that cause the quintic to split (into a quadratic and cubic factor) then correspond to the only nonzero square Fibonacci numbers of even index, $F_2=1$ and $F_{12}=144$:

- $(2)$ with $j=2$ gives $r=\pm15$
- $(1)$ with $j=5$ gives $r=\pm22440$
- $(2)$ with $j=7$ gives $r=\pm2759640$

Because there are only three special quintics, memorising the quadratic factors is feasible:

- $x^2\pm x+3$ divides $x^5-x\pm15$
- $x^2\mp12x+55$ divides $x^5-x\pm22440$
- $x^2\pm12x+377$ divides $x^5-x\pm2759640$

Then long division should suffice to find the cubic cofactor.

Answer (score 4):

I see there is an answer to 15. I tried, it appears there is no integer root to $x^5 - x \pm 22440.$ As 7 gives 16800 but 8 gives 32760. We arrive at
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + C)(x^2 + D x + E) = x^5 - x \pm 22440 $$
The point is not to solve the whole system at once, rather do one coefficient at a time and rewrite the system.  The degree four term must be 0, so $A+D = 0$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + C)(x^2 -A x + E) = x^5 - x \pm 22440 $$
Next the cubed term is zero, so $E-A^2 + B = 0, $ or $E = A^2 - B.$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + C)(x^2 -A x + (A^2 - B)) = x^5 - x \pm 22440 $$
Next $x^2$ has 0, or $A^3 - AB -AB + C = 0,$ or $C = 2AB - A^3,$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + (2AB -A^3))(x^2 -A x + (A^2 - B)) = x^5 - x \pm 22440 $$
Linear coefficient is $-1,$ so $A^2 B - B^2 - 2 A^2 B  + A^4 = -1,$ or $A^4 - A^2 B - B^2 = -1.$

Getting there; taking $x = A^2, y = B,$ we have $x^2 - xy - y^2 = -1,$ meaning that $x,y$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers... as $(3,2), (8,5), (21,13), (55,34), (144, 89).$ Since $x$ needs to be a square, we will try $A^2 = 144,$ $A = 12,$ $B = \pm 89$

One selection is
$$ (x^3 + 12 x^2 + 89 x + 408)(x^2 - 12 x + 55)  = x^5 - x + 22440$$
Just negating $x$ gives
$$ (-x^3 + 12 x^2 - 89 x + 408)(x^2 + 12 x + 55)  = -x^5 + x + 22440,$$
$$ (x^3- 12 x^2 + 89 x - 408)(x^2 + 12 x + 55)  = x^5 - x - 22440,$$

So there you go. We were able to use the first Fibonacci number that is also a square. Bigger than $1$ I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Wednesday morning. I wanted to see what happened with my Fibonacci trick for the largest constant term. I now know that the list of successful constant terms is a minor consequence of the fact that 144 is the largest square Fibonacci number. [This was proved by J. H. E. Cohn in 1964.](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s1-39/1/537/919331)

[Square Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012999/square-fibonacci-numbers)

[Summary of proof on square Fibonacci numbers](https://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/SquareFibonacci.html)

There is no integer root to $x^5 - x \pm 2759640.$  We arrive at
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + C)(x^2 + D x + E) = x^5 - x \pm 2759640 $$
The point is not to solve the whole system at once, rather do one coefficient at a time and rewrite the system.  The degree four term must be 0, so $A+D = 0$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + C)(x^2 -A x + E) = x^5 - x \pm 2759640 $$
Next the cubed term is zero, so $E-A^2 + B = 0, $ or $E = A^2 - B.$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + C)(x^2 -A x + (A^2 - B)) = x^5 - x \pm 2759640 $$
Next $x^2$ has 0, or $A^3 - AB -AB + C = 0,$ or $C = 2AB - A^3,$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + (2AB -A^3))(x^2 -A x + (A^2 - B)) = x^5 - x \pm 2759640 $$
Linear coefficient is $-1,$ so $A^2 B - B^2 - 2 A^2 B  + A^4 = -1,$ or $A^4 - A^2 B - B^2 = -1.$

Getting there; taking $x = A^2, y = B,$ we have $x^2 - xy - y^2 = -1,$ meaning that $x,y$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers... as $(3,2), (8,5), (21,13), (55,34), (144, 89), \cdots$ If we allow $y=B$ negative instead, we get
 $$ \color{purple}{(1,-2), (3,-5), (8,-13), (21,-34), (55, -89), (144, -233), \cdots}$$

Since $x$ needs to be a square, we will try $A^2 = 144,$ $A = \pm 12,$ $B =  -233$
$$ (x^3 + A x^2 + B x + (2AB -A^3))(x^2 -A x + (A^2 - B)) = x^5 - x \pm 2759640 $$
One selection is
$$ (x^3 - 12 x^2 - 233 x + 7320)(x^2 + 12 x + 377)  = x^5 - x + 2759640$$
Just negating $x$ gives
$$ (-x^3 - 12 x^2 + 233 x + 7320)(x^2 - 12 x + 377)  = -x^5 + x + 2759640,$$
$$ (x^3 + 12 x^2 - 233 x - 7320)(x^2 - 12 x + 377)  = x^5 - x - 2759640,$$

ALL OF THESE:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse
  a:  -12  b:  -233  2ab-a^3:  7320  a^2-b:  377  prod:  2759640
  a:  -12  b:  89  2ab-a^3:  -408  a^2-b:  55  prod:  -22440
  a:  -1  b:  -2  2ab-a^3:  5  a^2-b:  3  prod:  15
  a:  -1  b:  1  2ab-a^3:  -1  a^2-b:  0  prod:  0
  a:  0  b:  -1  2ab-a^3:  0  a^2-b:  1  prod:  0
  a:  0  b:  1  2ab-a^3:  0  a^2-b:  -1  prod:  0
  a:  1  b:  -2  2ab-a^3:  -5  a^2-b:  3  prod:  -15
  a:  1  b:  1  2ab-a^3:  1  a^2-b:  0  prod:  0
  a:  12  b:  -233  2ab-a^3:  -7320  a^2-b:  377  prod:  -2759640
  a:  12  b:  89  2ab-a^3:  408  a^2-b:  55  prod:  22440
```