# How to proof that 144 is the only Fibbonacci square number

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

From what i heard 144 is the only number which is a Fibonacci number and also a square number. I couldn‘t find any proof online tho. I checked Wikipedia and tried looking up a paper on google scholar, could someone show me the proof, or correct me if there isn‘t one. Thanks everyone.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012999/square-fibonacci-numbers

Comment: Should remark: $0,1$ are also  square Fibonacci numbers.  And $8$ is a Fibonacci cube, but there are no other perfect power Fibonacci numbers.